# How to respond to recruiters that have failed to keep their appointments?

Tags: communication, ethics, united-kingdom

Based in UK for info.

Over the last couple of months I've been contacted by recruiters on LinkedIn about job opportunities. One specific recruiter read my profile and outlined his job specification which both he and I agreed that I'd be a good match for.

So we scheduled a call to discuss further. I shared my number with him and told him I'd expect his call. Time came and went and no call from the recruiter.

A few days later he messages again and apologises and we schedule a call again time came and went. I dropped him a message on LinkedIn asking if we were still on the for the call.

No response. Again a week later he contacts me. No reference to the two previous missed appointments and no apologies asking again to schedule a call.

This time I have ignored his message. What's the best way of proceeding, personally I've felt it's not worth my time.

He is a in-house recruiter for a fairly well-known company.

Comment: I've always found that an email with an attachment containing a trojan can be a wonderful attitude adjustment tool

Comment: Slightly different question. My question is more about how to respond to bad recruiters. And not how to follow up an interview.

Comment: They're probably being paid for the number of responses they get from a spam shot or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an in-house recruiter of a *'fairly well known company'* doesn't follow up and keeps his promises, there are three options I can think of now:

1. Forget about it and deal with them as @Charmander explains in his answer.
2. Get in contact with the recruiter again hoping he will keep his promises (unlikely).
3. If you really would like to work there, you can bypass the sloppy
   recruiter and make an appointment with management of the according department or HR directly.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore him and remove him from your network so you don't have to deal with this recruiter ever again. I'd also add their number to my contact list and tag them with a keyword such as "avoid" or similar, so if they call you, you know you should ignore that call. Be mindful that someone else from that company might call you with that number, so perhaps if they call you, you can choose to pick up and wait for them to introduce themselves before making a decision on whether or not you want to carry on with the conversation.